# Get raw HTTP response with Retrofit - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit, dio, dart-http

How can I get raw http response with Retrofit?
I've tested with Response and ResponseBody, but both of the failed and said:

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'ResponseBody?'
```

[image]

I'm receiving a tar file, that's why I need to get a raw response to then call Response.body, to parse it with TarReader.

**Expected behavior:
be able to get a raw bytes of the response body.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You cant try to use HttpResponse from official source - https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit#get-original-http-response

@GET("/file")
Future<HttpResponse> getFile();